# How can I fill the rounded edge space with the side div color?

Tags: html, css, layout

I would like to make using CSS something like the image below.

[Expected layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuFgT.png)

[New expected layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIlXe.png)

Answer (score -1):

Nest three divs inside each other, with descending width but the same height.
With the `border-radius` you get the round corners.
Finally you assign them different colors.

```css
html {
  background: #f1faff;
}

div {
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.div1 {
  width: 300px;
  background: #e0ecfa;
}

.div2 {
  width: 250px;
  background: #fff;
}

.div3 {
  width: 50px;
  background: #4ed4b8;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <div class="div3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can merge same stylings under the same selector (like here the `div`). Additionally each div gets its own style.

Comment: Could you give some explanation rather than just code so that people understand what is being suggested.

Comment: Thanks for your response @SvenEberth .

Sorry, but I didn't provide enough information, so the way you suggested I did too, but I'm having trouble thinking of a way that looks good to add content to each div like this new image I added.

Comment: Please take my answer and try to add html and css by yourself. If you fail, you can post your attempt and we can help you. But SO is not a coding-service. My answer was already much more than necessary.